# Socket.io: websocket connection failed and keep get 404 error in client

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I use socket.io to setup websocket, but I fail to make connection successfully.
in server part, I see the get call.but in client, I got 404 `GET http://localhost:6543/socket.io/?uuid=258c4ab9-b263-47ca-ab64-83fe99ea03d4&transport=polling&t=MxE5ufA net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
and connection

server - typescript with express server
app.ts

```
const app = inversify.get<any>(EXPRESS_SYMBOL);
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
    console.log('Connected client');
    ....
});
```

client - angular
socketserivce

```
export class SocketService {

  private socket;

  public initSocket(uuid: string): void {
    this.socket =
      socketIo(ENDPOINT, {
        query: `uuid=${uuid}`
      });
  }
```

Comment: What is your server environment?  Local computer?  Hosted server?  If it's a hosted environment, it may need to be properly configured to allow a webSocket/socket.io connection.

Comment: And, silly question, did you start your server with `http.listen(portNumber)`?  And are both client and server using the same port?  Does your Express server otherwise work for regular http requests?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
export class SocketService {

  private socket;

  public initSocket(uuid: string): void {
  setTimeout (resp => {
   this.socket =
      socketIo(ENDPOINT, {
        query: `uuid=${uuid}`
      });
    }, 100);    
  }
```

let me know if it is working or not

Comment: @jfriend00 socket object takes time to initialise so in one of my project i put a `setTimeout(resp => { })` and it is working as expected.